# How would a simple efficient language look like?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

Let's imagine that for some reason we had to create an artificial language from scratch and we wanted this language to be both **simple** and **efficient**. By that I mean that the language was *easy to learn* for everyone and that it needed *very little words (and sounds)* to communicate any message. What characteristics would this language have?

Comment: It would have a lot of ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by "very little words", you mean "very few", and not "very short". Every language is completely easy to learn as a first language, and no language is universally trivial for everybody to learn as a second (adult) language. Since all languages are the same as first languages, I assume you mean "easy to learn as an adult".

To be easy to learn, there should be few rules (which doesn't mean that things are chaotic, it means that the *system* of rules is simple, not involving lots of very specific rules and obscure rule-interactions). The best way to achieve the desideratum of "easiness", the rules should be maximally surface-true. For example, if the verb is always the second word in the sentence, that rule should really be true, and not complicated by something like "unless the subject is a question word".

Any form of grammatical marking within words adds complexity, so there won't be any morphology – it will all be syntax. In other words, more like Chinese or Vietnamese, except not as hard to pronounce. The biggest challenge is constructing vocabulary. Suppose that you determine that there have to be at least 30,000 nouns and 10,000 verbs. If you have 12 consonants and 5 vowels, and if syllables can have up to 2 consonants at the beginning and at the end, you can easily get over 100,000 single-syllable words, which is a substantial number. However, this will probably require you to have word like [pdakp], [dmikn] and so on, and this will most likely cause problems for the majority of people. So words should have only one consonant at the beginning and end of the syllable. But then if you want to have 100,000 words and you stick with the CVC formula, 12 consonants and 5 vowels, you'd need words up to 16 syllables long in order to get 100,000 words – I think people would have trouble with such long words. If you increase the count of consonants to 20 and vowels to 7, you might manage keep words to no more than 8 syllables, but that is still pretty substantial.

One approach followed by people inventing languages is to simply cap the number of words in the lexicon at something small like 10,000 and then you can have an inventory of about 14 consonants and 5 vowels. But 10,000 words is unrealistic for general use that would include words like "fox", "raccoon", "husky", "panda", "malamute", "bear", "poodle", "seal", "skunk", "jackal", "weasel", "walrus", "wolf" and so on. People attempt to eliminate the need for many words by using phrases, calling the jackal "fox dog" and raccoon "trash panda", but eventually these end up become arbitrary learned combinations that function like words (if seal is "water dog", what is "walrus"? And shouldn't fox be something like "cat dog", so jackal should be "cat dog dog"?).

The English consonant inventory is not particularly difficult, except perhaps [θ ð], though the phonetic value of "r" is a bit of a nuisance. Perhaps a consonant inventory of [p t k tʃ b d g dʒ f s ʃ v z ʒ m n l r w y] would cause the least inconvenience for the most people. We probably have too many vowels and should not go beyond [i e ɛ a ə ɔ o u]. We could get near 100,000 words with this inventory if you can tolerate 7-syllable words. Or, you could complicate syllable structure by allowing at least *some* CC onsets – but that will cause problems for some speakers. In other words, there's no way to compute an ideal "maximal benefit for most" system.

Actually, if you factor in the number of speakers of different languages (so that the billion and a half speakers of English get a certain vote against adding pharyngeals, and the few hundred speakers of Piraha get a certain vote against adding [e, l] which don't exist in their language), you will probably find that the simplest and most efficient language is Mandarin.

Comment: *if seal is "water dog", what is "walrus"?*  Well I have seen *sea elephant*, *sea bull*, *sea bear*.  And also *lion whale/dragon* and of course *whale horse*.